# How does the fee get calculated in hardhat?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I have a solidity method which transfers ether like below code:

```
function testTransfer() public payable {
        payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);
    }
```

I am using `hardhat` to do unit test on this method.

```
    const balanceBefore = await ethers.provider.getBalance(address);
    console.log('balanceBefore', balanceBefore.toString());
    await contract.testTransfer({value: 100});
    const balanceAfter = await ethers.provider.getBalance(address);
    console.log('balanceAfter', balanceAfter.toString());
    console.log('different:', parseFloat(balanceBefore.toString()) - parseFloat(balanceAfter.toString()));
```

The output is:

```
balanceBefore 10000000000000000000000
balanceAfter 9999999941570704178388
different: 58429295034368
```

as you can see, the `testTransfer` in solidity only transfers 100 wei to the owner of the contract. But the balance different before and after run the method is `58429295034368` wei which is a lot larger than `100`. I can only think there is extra fee cost on running the code but I don't expect the fee is that expensive. Is there something not correct in hardhat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fee is approx. 0.000058 ETH == 58k Gwei.

Assuming the function costs roughly 29k gas units to execute (21k base for the transaction + 8k to read the output of the `owner()` function and to perform the transfer) => the gas price results in **2 Gwei per gas unit**.

Which is expected in the local testing environment.

If you wish, you can change the `gasPrice` value in your config file ([docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config#json-rpc-based-networks)).

For comparison - current (March 2024) `gasPrice` on the mainnet is usually in the tens of Gwei per gas unit, sometimes over a 100. Source: https://etherscan.io/gastracker

Comment: where do you get those value from? `21k base for the transaction + 8k to read `

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao 1) 21k: I don't remember the exact source where I learned about it, but it's mentioned for example [here](https://ethereum.org/cs/developers/docs/transactions/#on-gas). Each transaction costs 21k gas units + any fees associated with executing a smart contract... 2) 8k: Ballpark number assumed based on the functionality, but I verified it in Remix emulator. Each low-level operation (storage read, calling another address, ...) has a fixed amount of gas units assigned. List [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/opcodes/).

Comment: Thanks for that. I remember each network has base gas which could mean where the 21K is from